# conflict in position of recyclerview items when put two fragments in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two fragments, one contains summary of many items in recycler view and another contains details for these items. In landscape mode in tablet: I put the two fragments in the same activity.

In details fragment I have next button to navigate to next element,but when I reached to the last element and press on button it is navigate to the item before the last and when press on this element it is navigating to the last and so on , although this problem Does not happen in portrait mode

this code of first activity

```
public class FavouritesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemClickListener{
int activity;
ViewPager vp;
public static final String VIEW_POSITION="view_position";
public static final String CONDITION="condition";
public static final String ACTIVITY="activity";
SharedPreferences settings;
String locale;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favouritesactivity_layout);
    activity = getIntent().getIntExtra("activity",1);
    settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
    locale = settings.getString("locale", "en-US");
    /*Locale.setDefault(Locale.forLanguageTag(locale));
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(locale));
    //config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());*/
    String languageToLoad  = locale; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.addPages(vp);
    TabLayout tab=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.mTab_Id);
    tab.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tab.setupWithViewPager(vp);
    tab.addOnTabSelectedListener(listener(vp));
}

// ADD ALL PAGES
private void addPages(ViewPager vp) {
    MyFragPagerAdapter adapter=new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addPage(new SunsetFavouritesFragment());
    adapter.addPage(new SunriseFavouritesFragment());

    // SET ADAPTER TO PAGER
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener listener(final ViewPager pager){

    return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    double inches=getScreenInches();
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            && inches >=7){
        int tabId=vp.getCurrentItem();
        FavouritesDetailsFragment fragment = FavouritesDetailsFragment.newInstance(6
                                            ,getIntent().getIntExtra(FavouritesActivity.CONDITION,tabId+1),
                                            getIntent().getIntExtra(FavouritesActivity.VIEW_POSITION,position));
        replaceFragment(fragment, "SecondFragment");
    }else{
        int tabId=vp.getCurrentItem();
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,FavouriteDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(CONDITION,tabId+1);
        intent.putExtra(VIEW_POSITION,position);
        intent.putExtra(ACTIVITY,6);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    try {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.azkaarfav_detail_fragment, fragment, tag).commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("", e.toString());
    }
}
```

this code of second fragment

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
final AzkarForm azkarForm=azkarForms.get(position);
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.icon:
        if (azkarForm.isFavourite() ){
            if(CONDITION == 1) {
                putFav(false, "fav", azkarForms.get(position).getId());
            }
            else {
                putFav(false, "fav_evening", azkarForms.get(position).getId());
            }
            azkarForms.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.fav_sample_model:
        Intent intent1=new Intent(getActivity(),FavouriteDetailsActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("position", 2);
        intent1.putExtra("activity", 6);
        intent1.putExtra("condition", 1);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent1);
        break;
    case R.id.next:
        Boolean next_vibrate=settings.getBoolean("sett_5",false);
        vibe = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if(next_vibrate==true)
            vibe.vibrate(100);
        rv.scrollToPosition(position+1);
        break;
    case R.id.press:
        Boolean press_vibrate=settings.getBoolean("sett_4",false);
        Boolean sound_count=settings.getBoolean("sett_6",false);
        Boolean next_count=settings.getBoolean("sett_3",false);
        vibe = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.ringpress);
        int num;
        item=list.get(position);
        Button press = (Button) view;
        if(press_vibrate==true)
            vibe.vibrate(100);
        if(sound_count == true)
            mp.start();
        int currentNum = Integer.parseInt(press.getText().toString());
        num = item.getNumber();
        if (currentNum < num) {
            if(ACTIVITY == 3)
                putPress(currentNum,"presses",position);
            else
                putPress(currentNum,"presses_evening",position);
            currentNum++;
        }
        if(currentNum == num)
        {
            if(ACTIVITY == 3)
                putPress(currentNum,"presses",position);
            else
                putPress(currentNum,"presses_evening",position);

            if(position == azkarForms.size()-1){
                currentNum = num;
                press.setText(String.valueOf(currentNum));
            }
            if(next_count == true)
                rv.scrollToPosition(position+1);
            else {
                press.setText(String.valueOf(currentNum));
            }
        }
        press.setText(String.valueOf(currentNum));
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in layout , I modified relative layout to constraint layout